# How to get a basic SOAP api request working with Javascript

Tags: javascript, soap

I need some help getting a basic SOAP request working.
I have read various posts and websites about the CORS issue and installed a chrome browser extension. When I run the code with response headers in. Even just the content-type header, I get the following error:
*request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*

When I do the same thing with no headers I get:
*415 error - The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.*

Here is the Javascript code:

```
var url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

//xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");


xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = `<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
  <FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
    <Fahrenheit>75</Fahrenheit>
  </FahrenheitToCelsius>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>`;

xhr.send(data);
```

Here is the basic Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SOAP JavaScript Client Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 id="Test"></h3>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Im really confused as to what I have done wrong since similar code works on Reqbin website.

Comment: Here is the response header if it helps:access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:5500
allow: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK
cache-control: public
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://mycourses.w3schools.com;
date: Thu, 18 May 2023 16:51:45 GMT
public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
x-content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://mycourses.w3schools.com;
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue as you when getting to know Soap, after some digging I found that a solution not so optimal but just fine for getting to know soap is, running chrome without CORS enabled.

To do this you need to navigate to your chrome-folder:

```
cd "c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"
```

And run the chrome application without CORS like so:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="c:/ChromeDevSession"
```

I hope this works as I remember vividly how I struggled with this issue a couple months ago :)